# VBA: How do I filter by an array that I created from range of cells

Tags: arrays, vba, autofilter

I know I am creating the array correctly and I have used the autofilter code with arrays before but for some reason when I try to filter by a dynamic array only the first value of my array comes back. I create the array from an already filtered list on one sheet and then go to a different sheet to filter by the array values.

```
 Dim StepArray As Variant
 Dim LastRow As Long


  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row
  StepArray = Range("C4:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
  Sheet2.Select
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row
  Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 5)).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=StepArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** to add the case the filtered range is a contiguous one

Range values to array doesn't work with non contiguous ranges like a filtered one is much likely to be

you have to loop through range and fill the array, like

```
Function GetFilteredValues(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim iCell As Long

    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Count)
    For Each cell In rng
        iCell = iCell + 1
        arr(iCell) = cell.Value
    Next
    GetFilteredValues = arr
End Function
```

to be used in your main code as follows

```
StepArray = GetFilteredValues(Range("C4:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

---

Should filtered range be actually a contiguous one then you have to transpose it and get a one-dimensional array

```
StepArray = Application.Transpose(Range("C4:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value)
```

Comment: Later in my code I transpose the array, and all the filtered values are present, I don't think the above is necessary. The only problem I have is filtering by the array.

Comment: I don't get you. You wrote _"I create the array from an already filtered list"_. Well, to handle this issue you _have_ to act as per my code (or equivalent). So either you _do need_ an array out of a not contiguous (filtered) range or you _don't_.

Comment: I have all the values I want in my array I just can't seem to filter by them in the autofilter on the second sheet

Comment: If your filtered range is (luckily) a contiguous one then see last part of edited answer

Comment: Yes the transposition to the one dimensional array worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`StepArray` is treated as a value because you didn't `set` it to be a range.

```
Set StepArray = Range("C4:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Maybe better? Just a suggestion, I never tried to filter with arrays.

Comment: this doesn't work. you'd better post answers after you tested them, while "suggestions" can be given in comments along with the _disclaimer_ they are such things. you may want to delete this post for the sake of both not cheating future readers and save yourself heavy downvoting

Comment: Tried it, no luck "Autofilter of Range Class Failed" error came up.

Comment: @user3598756 Hello mate, I'm so sorry you are angry but ... I can't comment yet =D I just started yesterday and don't have as much reputation as you do =(

Comment: @JiheL, I'm not angry. Just telling you how things ought to go on around here. You may want to take a SO tour (see help). Coming back to your answer: OP's code had such a statement as `StepArray = Range("C4:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value`-> he wanted to store a range values in a `Variant` array and use it as the Criteria for a subsequent `AutoFilter()`. He didn't want to set it as a `Range` object. So your _suggestion_ was out of track and you would have known that if you carefully read the question and knew the related objects and methods. Otherwise you can use comments